# Generating a waveform using ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am trying to generate a waveform image using ffmpeg.

I have successfully made a waveform image, however it doesn't look very nice...

I have been looking around to try and style the image to make it look nicer, however I have been unable to find any information on this or any tutorials on this.

I am using PHP and shell_exec to create the waveform.

I am aware that there are php library that can do this but due to file format this is a lengthy process.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
$command = 'convertvid\bin\ffmpeg -i Temp\\'.$file.' -y -lavfi showwavespic=split_channels=0:s='.$width.'x50 Temp\\'.$PNGFileName;
shell_exec($command);
```

Basically I would like to add a line through the middle as there are blank spots at the moment and would like to be able to set the background and wave colour.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

## Default waveform

[image: Default waveform]

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -filter_complex showwavespic -frames:v 1 output.png
```

#### Notes

- Notice the segment of silent audio in the middle (see "Fancy waveform" below if you want to see how to add a line).
- The background is transparent.
- Default colors are red (left channel) and green (right channel) for a stereo input. The color is mixed where the channels overlap.
- You can change the channel colors with the `colors` option, such as `"showwavespic=colors=blue|yellow"`. See a [list of valid color names](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Color) or use hexadecimal notation, such as `#ffcc99`.
- See the [showwavespic filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwavespic) for additional options.
- If you want a video instead of an image use the [showwaves filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwaves).

## Fancy waveform

[image: Fancy waveform]

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono, \
 compand=gain=-6, \
 showwavespic=s=600x120:colors=#9cf42f[fg]; \
 color=s=600x120:color=#44582c, \
 drawgrid=width=iw/10:height=ih/5:color=#9cf42f@0.1[bg]; \
 [bg][fg]overlay=format=auto,drawbox=x=(iw-w)/2:y=(ih-h)/2:w=iw:h=1:color=#9cf42f" \
-frames:v 1 output.png
```

#### Explanation of options

1. [aformat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aformat) downsamples the audio to mono. Otherwise, by default, a stereo input would result in a waveform with a different color for each channel (see **Default waveform** example above).
2. [compand](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#compand) modifies the dynamic range of the audio to make the waveform look less flat. It makes a less accurate representation of the actual audio, but can be more visually appealing for some inputs.
3. [showwavespic](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwavespic) makes the actual waveform.
4. [color](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#allrgb_002c-allyuv_002c-color_002c-haldclutsrc_002c-nullsrc_002c-rgbtestsrc_002c-smptebars_002c-smptehdbars_002c-testsrc) source filter is used to make a colored background that is the same size as the waveform.
5. [drawgrid](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawgrid) adds a grid over the background. The grid does not represent anything, but is just for looks. The grid color is the same as the waveform color (`#9cf42f`), but opacity is set to 10% (`@0.1`).
6. [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) will place `[bg]` (what I named the filtergraph for the background) behind `[fg]` (the waveform).
7. Finally, [drawbox](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawbox) will make the horizontal line so any silent areas are not blank.

## Gradient example

[image: Gradient example]

Using [gradients filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#gradients):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "gradients=s=1920x1080:c0=000000:c1=434343:x0=0:x1=0:y0=0:y1=1080,drawbox=x=(iw-w)/2:y=(ih-h)/2:w=iw:h=1:color=#0000ff[bg];[0:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono,showwavespic=s=1920x1080:colors=#0068ff[fg];[bg][fg]overlay=format=auto" -vframes:v 1 output.png
```

## Color background

[image: waveform with simple color background]

```
ffmpeg -i input.opus -filter_complex "color=c=blue[color];aformat=channel_layouts=mono,showwavespic=s=1280x720:colors=white[wave];[color][wave]scale2ref[bg][fg];[bg][fg]overlay=format=auto" -frames:v 1 output.png
```

The [scale2ref](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref) filter automatically makes the background the same size as the waveform.

## Image background

Of course you can use an image or video instead for the background:

[image: Image background example]

```
ffmpeg -i audio.flac -i background.jpg -filter_complex \
"[1:v]scale=600:-1,crop=iw:120[bg]; \
 [0:a]showwavespic=s=600x120:colors=cyan|aqua[fg]; \
 [bg][fg]overlay=format=auto" \
-q:v 3 showwavespic_bg.jpg
```

---

## Getting waveform stats and data

Use the [astats](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#astats) filter. Many stats are available: RMS, peak, min, max, difference, etc.

### RMS level per audio frame

Example to get standard RMS level measured in dBFS per audio frame:

```
ffprobe -v error -f lavfi -i "amovie=input.wav,astats=metadata=1:reset=1" -show_entries frame_tags=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level -of csv=p=0 > rms.log
```

### Peak level per second

Add the [asetnsamples](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#asetnsamples) filter.

```
ffprobe -v error -f lavfi -i "amovie=input.wav,asetnsamples=44100,astats=metadata=1:reset=1" -show_entries frame_tags=lavfi.astats.Overall.Peak_level -of csv=p=0
```

### Same as above but with timestamps

```
ffprobe -v error -f lavfi -i "amovie=input.wav,asetnsamples=44100,astats=metadata=1:reset=1" -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time:frame_tags=lavfi.astats.Overall.Peak_level -of csv=p=0
```

### Output to file

Just append `> output.log` to the end of your command:

```
ffprobe -v error -f lavfi -i "amovie=input.wav,asetnsamples=44100,astats=metadata=1:reset=1" -show_entries frame_tags=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level -of csv=p=0 > output.log
```

### JSON

```
ffprobe -v error -f lavfi -i "amovie=input.wav,asetnsamples=44100,astats=metadata=1:reset=1" -show_entries frame_tags=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level -of json > output.json
```

Comment: Thanks LongNeckbeard, you are the FFmpeg master! When I did "boring default wav" command it already had a transparent background and red wave, i didn't have to add the extra stuff which works great.

Comment: `Option 'colors' not found` -- i assume i need a build flag

Comment: @chovy Your `ffmpeg` is too old. See the [FFmpeg Download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to "static builds" for your OS.

Comment: @llogan is there a way to generate waveform data in an array format, so that it can be plotted manually?

Comment: @Ankush Can you show my an example of what you want?

Comment: @llogan So what I am trying to do is, In Android, I am trying to make a UI that shows one streak for every second of the audio clip. So I was wondering if there's a way to get an array of amplitudes (average) per second. For example, if a clip is 10 seconds long, I want an array of 10 size where each element is the amplitude for every second. Then I can manually plot these 10 array elements in a UI. Have a look at this image and hover over it for viewing comments  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u375nXkVe8ekiMbQToVNGekgAgLujKjj/view

Comment: @Ankush Assuming an input with a 44100 sample rate try `ffprobe -v error -f lavfi -i amovie=input.wav,asetnsamples=44100,astats=metadata=1:reset=1 -show_entries frame_tags=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level -of csv=p=0` See [astats](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#astats-1) filter for other stats to choose from.

Comment: @llogan Thanks for the response. I'll check it out and will update in case of any queries. Thanks once again.

Comment: What if we don't want a picture of the waveform, but rather the raw output file using `-f data`? Which extension should we put? I always got "Unable to find a suitable output format for ..." no matter the output format. I ideally want it as a JSON, but raw data would be fine.

Comment: @Jérémy See the "RMS level per audio frame" command in the answer, but change `-of csv=p=0 > rms.log` to `-of json > output.json`

Comment: You can also use FFmpeg to produce an audio waveform video stream i created an online tool which does this you can see the code in the browsers console. https://davidclews.com/article/58.html