# Run ffmpeg multiple commands

Tags: ffmpeg

Im using this ffmpeg command to convert mp3 to wav:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 64k -ar 16000 audio.wav
```

and this command to create waveform from audio.wav:

```
wav2png --foreground-color=ffb400aa --background-color=2e4562ff -o example4.png papa2.wav
```

I would love to know, how to run this commands multiple? For example, when conversion from .mp3 to .wav is done, then run the wav2png command.

Thank You!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have several options here:

## Option 1: Use `&&`

In Bash you can use an *[and list](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/list-cons.html#LISTCONSREF)* to concatenate commands. Each command will be executed one after the other. The *and list* will terminate when a command fails, or when all commands have been successfully executed.

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 audio.wav && wav2png -o output.png audio.wav
```

- Using `-acodec libmp3lame` when outputting to WAV makes no sense, so I removed that.
- WAV ignores bitrate options, so I removed `-ab`.
- Do you really need to change the audio rate (`-ar`)? Removed.

## Option 2: Pipe from `ffmpeg` to `wav2png`

Instead of making a temporary WAV file you can pipe the output from `ffmpeg` directly to `wav2png`:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -f wav - | wav2png -o output.png /dev/stdin
```

## Option 3: Just use `ffmpeg`

Saving the best for last, you can try the [showwavespic filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwavespic).

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i music.wav -filter_complex showwavespic=s=640x320 showwaves.png
```

- If you want to make a video of the wave form, then try [showwaves](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwaves).
- You can see a colored example at [Generating a waveform using `ffmpeg`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32276471/1109017).