# How to run multiple ffmpeg command in using && or |

Tags: ffmpeg

I have create an repeated audio track and then merge it with video. so I have used && operator for that but it gives me and error
sample command is like
"-stream_loop 2 -i /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Hard.mp3 -c copy -y /storage/emulated/0/Movies/sfsdf.mp3 && -i /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Vid.mp4 -i /storage/emulated/0/Movies/sfsdf.mp3 -map 0v0 -map 1a0 -y -acodec copy -vcodec copy -preset ultrafast -async 1 /storage/emulated/0/Movies/audio_loop.mp4"

the commands are seperated by &&
both the commands run well individually but using && operator it will not work.
Does anybody having idea about it?

refernece link : [Run ffmpeg multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33963263/run-ffmpeg-multiple-commands)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I am creating repeat audio file i.e. sfsdf.mp3 from exiting audio file i.e. Hard.mp3. But it shows error like sfsdf.mp3 does not exist(that is used in the second command to merge sfsdf,mp3 audio with Vid.mp4 video). I think the && operator to run multiple command did not works

Comment: For a quick test try to sleep a bit between commands: `cmd1 && sleep 1 && cmd2`

Comment: Thanks for your reply I have tried you suggestion and formed command like "-stream_loop 1 -i /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Hard.mp3 -c copy -y /storage/emulated/0/Movies/sfsdf.mp3 && sleep 1 && -i /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Vid.mp4 -i /storage/emulated/0/Movies/sfsdf.mp3 -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -y -acodec copy -vcodec copy -preset ultrafast -async 1 /storage/emulated/0/Movies/audio_loop.mp4"  but still no use