# using ffmpeg to create a wavefile image from opus

Tags: ffmpeg

I have been trying to use ffmpeg to create a wavefile image from an opus file.  so far i have found three different methods but cannot seem to determine which one is the best.

The end result is hopefully to have a sound-wave that is only approx. 55px in height.  The image will become part of a css background-image.

Adapted from [Generating a waveform using `ffmpeg`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32276471/1109017):

> ffmpeg -i file.opus -filter_complex
>   "showwavespic,colorbalance=bs=0.5:gm=0.3:bh=-0.5,drawbox=x=(iw-w)/2:y=(ih-h)/2:w=iw:h=1:color=black@0.5"
>   file.png

which produces this image:
[image]

Next, I found this one (and my favorite because of the simplicity):

> ffmpeg -i test.opus -lavfi showwavespic=split_channels=1:s=1024x800 test.png

And here is what that one looks like:

[image]

Finally, this one from [FFmpeg Wiki: Waveform](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Waveform), but it seems less efficient using a second utility (gnuplot) rather than just ffmpeg:

> ffmpeg -i  file.opus    -ac 1 -filter:a
>   aresample=4000 -map 0:a -c:a pcm_s16le -f data - |  \
>   gnuplot  -e "set
>   terminal png size 525,050;set output
>   'file.png';unset key;unset tics;unset border; set
>   lmargin 0;set rmargin 0;set tmargin 0;set bmargin 0; plot '

[image]

Option two is my favorite, but i dont like the margins on the top and bottom of the waveforms.

Option three (using gnuplot) makes the best 'shaped' image for our needs, since the initial spike in sound seems to make the rest almost too small to use (lines tend to almost disappear) when the image is sized at only 50 pixels high.

Any suggestions how might best approach this?  I really understand very little about any of the options I see, except of course for the size.  Note too i have 10's of thousands to process, so naturally i want to make a wise choice at the very beginning.

Comment: There is nothing "preferred" about the method used in the wiki you linked to: it is simply outdated and older than the showwavespic filter. (Oddly, I was looking at that article and considering updating it minutes before seeing your question).

Comment: thank you lordNeckBeard - i did notice the link to what i had assumed was the preferred method has been disabled!  again, i prefer option two because of the simplicity, but only if i can easily "level out" the wave a little.  here is an example opus file -  http://comptonpeslonline.com//html5Audio/newWaveSurfer/test.opus

Comment: sorry - when i say "preferred" it was because that was the first page that came up when i searched for "ffmpeg wavefile" - that's why i incorrectly assumed it was the preferred method.

Comment: That wiki page was recently renamed: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Waveform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]
[image]
<sub>Original and manipulated waveforms.</sub>

You can use the [compand](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#compand) filter to adjust the dynamic range. [drawbox](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawbox) is then used to make the horizontal line.

```
ffmpeg -i test.opus -filter_complex \
"compand=gain=-6,showwavespic=s=525x50, \
 drawbox=x=(iw-w)/2:y=(ih-h)/2:w=iw:h=1:color=white" \
-vframes 1 output.png
```

It won't be quite as accurate of a representation of your audio as the original waveform, but it may be an improvement visually; especially on such a wide scale.

Also see [FFmpeg Wiki: Waveform](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Waveform).